# Apache don't actualize new css

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a django server which is run by mod_wsgi and apache.

Today when I tried to update the css in one of my html pages, the css file was updated but apache was still showing the old css. I tried to rename the css file but it didn't work out.

What can I do ?

Thank you

Comment: Run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: You rocks, it works. I don't know how I was missing that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the pages are being cached. Probably with browser caching. Try and clear your cache and/or open up your dev tools and go to network and disable caching.